# .net core EF DB initiallize

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

```
 if(_db.Database.GetPendingMigrations().Count() > 0)
            {
                _db.Database.Migrate();
            }
```

I don't know what these two functions are for and why they are used, so please explain in detail.

Comment: Did you try searching for them? The docs have all the details you need there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It checks if there are any non-applied migrations in your DB model and applies them to the DB. If you don't know what that means, you should read through the EF migration introduction docs

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/managing-schemas/migrations/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli